# Excluding MOTO payments from PSD2/SCA

Tags: opayo

Under SCA Mail order/Telephone orders are excluded (MOTO payments). Stripe have confirmed they have a flag that can be sent with the request to indicate this and they guaranteed 3D Secure will not be triggered.

Is there a similar facility for Sage Pay? Our customer takes a lot of telephone orders via card and many of these do not have access to Internet technology to do 3D secure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an AccountType property on a request with values "E", "M" and "C". "M" being the one used for MO-TO payments.

Comment: Yes I did see this in the integration guidelines however this seems like a pre-existing flag from before SCA was introduced. It's frustrating that the Sage-Page integration guides still don't mention SCA at all so you can imagine my hestitation to just assume that setting M will carry us through on the 14th September!